Servicebus and library override connection string
I have two different applications where I use service bus registration in the same way, for one it works, and for the other, it does not. So where is the problem?
In line with AddServiceBusClient() I am putting connection string form settings and I am 100% sure that this cs exist.
public static IServiceCollection AddProjectMessagingSubscriptions(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddHostedService<HumanResourcesTopicReciever>();
    services.AddHostedService<SelfServiceTopicReciever>();

    var messagingConfiguration = configuration.GetSection("MessagingOptions");

    services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddServiceBusClient(connectionString: messagingConfiguration["ConnectionString"]);
        builder.AddClient<ServiceBusReceiver, ServiceBusClientOptions>(
            (_, _, provider) => provider.GetService<ServiceBusClient>()
                .CreateReceiver(messagingConfiguration["SelfServiceTopic"], messagingConfiguration["SelfServiceTopicSubscriptionName"])).WithName("SelfServiceTopic");

        builder.AddClient<ServiceBusReceiver, ServiceBusClientOptions>(
            (_, _, provider) => provider.GetService<ServiceBusClient>()
                 .CreateReceiver(messagingConfiguration["HumanResourcesTopic"], messagingConfiguration["HumanResourcesTopicSubscriptionName"])).WithName("HumanResourcesTopicSubscription");

    });

    return services;
}

When I run the application I get this error:

It doesn't make sense because the cs has been transferred! It looks like the library is overwriting it for me and inserting a null there, but why?
Using rider I debug the servicebus library and I am sure that the connection string is passing correctly. At some point, this value is replaced with null

Are you using azure function or else asp .net application? and can you provide full code and where does you con string is present and how you are getting it.

classic .net 8 web app.  Same as the example, only instead of an environment variable it explicitly passes cs

This may be due to the factory not reading your config value until the client is requested by DI for the first time.   Have you tried reading your connection string into a local variable outside of the DI registration and using that local variable when registering the client?

I have used below code and it worked perfectly fine for me:
appsettings.json:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "RithBus": {
    "ConStr": "Endpoint=sb://rithwik.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=uqmgMXqXd14="
  }
  }

Program.cs:
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

var rith = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
rith.Services.AddRazorPages();
rith.Services.AddSingleton(new ServiceBusClient(rith.Configuration["RithBus:ConStr"]));
rith.Services.AddHostedService<RithServiceBusReciver>();

var app = rith.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

RithServiceBusReciver.cs:
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;

public class RithServiceBusReciver : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ServiceBusProcessor _rith;
    private readonly ILogger<RithServiceBusReciver> r_log;

    public RithServiceBusReciver(ServiceBusClient client, ILogger<RithServiceBusReciver> logger)
    {
        _rith = client.CreateProcessor("rithtopic", "rithsub");
        _rith.ProcessMessageAsync += Rith_ProcessMessages;
        _rith.ProcessErrorAsync += Rith_ErrorHandlerAsync;
        r_log = logger;
    }
    private Task Rith_ProcessMessages(ProcessMessageEventArgs rags)
    {
        string body = rags.Message.Body.ToString();
        r_log.LogInformation($"Hello Rithwik, The Received message is : {body}");
        return rags.CompleteMessageAsync(rags.Message);
    }
    private Task Rith_ErrorHandlerAsync(ProcessErrorEventArgs rags)
    {
        r_log.LogError(rags.Exception, $"Hello Rithwik, The Error message is : {rags.Exception.Message}");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken ch_token)
    {
        await _rith.StartProcessingAsync(ch_token);
        await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, ch_token);
    }

    public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken ch_token)
    {
        await _rith.StopProcessingAsync(ch_token);
        await base.StopAsync(ch_token);
    }
}

Output:
Sent Message :

Received Message:


This fixed my issue
            services.AddSingleton<ServiceBusClient>(x => new ServiceBusClient(messagingConfiguration["ConnectionString"]));

